# datamembers in constructor without declaring outside constructor

Tags: javascript

In javascript, Can we define a datamembers/any datastucture without declaring them outside constructor
Like this :

```
class Queue {

    constructor() {
        this.items = [];
    }

}
```

Comment: What happens when you try?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, we can define data members inside the constructor without declaring them outside. In the example above, the data member "items" is declared inside the constructor without being declared outside.

Comment: and one more que...Consider the above example, Suppose we want to access the "item" using a function which is not a part of class,then how can we access it ?

Comment: @krish in javascript it's not hidden, you can simply access it as `queue.items` supposing  `queue` is a `Queue` instance, i.e., `queue = new Queue()`